# Pandas dataframe groupby value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this code it is perfectly working , but when i remove "RIAGENDR" from

```
dx=dm.groupby(["RIAGENDR","RIDAGEYR"])["DMDMARTL"]
```

it show me error but why what is the reason ??
please help me with that !!!

````
    dm=ds[ds["RIAGENDR"]=="male"]
    dm.RIDAGEYR=pd.cut(dm.RIDAGEYR,[18,30,40,50,60,70,80,100])
    dx=dm.groupby(["RIAGENDR","RIDAGEYR"])["DMDMARTL"]
    dx=dx.value_counts()
    dx=dx.unstack()
    dx = dx.apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=0) 
    #dx=dx.to_string(float_format="%.3f")
    dx
    ```
````

Comment: What error are you getting? Try, `dx=dm.groupby("RIDAGEYR")["DMDMARTL"]`  Removing the extract brackets not need because you have one column and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

**You should remove the `[]` brackets from within the `groupby` operation**.

To be clear, if you want to group by 2 variables you should use the below code which uses a `list` of variables:

```
dx=dm.groupby(["RIAGENDR","RIDAGEYR"])["DMDMARTL"]
```

If you want to group by 1 variable, you should not use a `list` of variables, just a single one:

```
dx=dm.groupby("RIAGENDR")["DMDMARTL"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use [] when you have single variable:

```
dx=dm.groupby(["RIAGENDR","RIDAGEYR"])["DMDMARTL"]
```

or one way is to use:

```
dx=dm.groupby(by=["RIAGENDR"])
```

you can get this on following link somewhere in Hierarchical Indexes:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html